# In the Unity dependency injection framework, is there an equivalent to running BuildUp with InjectionConstructors?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, constructor-injection

One thing I've always wanted in an DI framework is the ability to use injection constructors with objects that interact with the framework only to consume services. For instance:

```
public class ServiceClass : IServiceInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ConsumerClass // explicitly implements no interfaces
{
    private readonly IServiceInterface service;
    public IServiceInterface Service { get { return service; } }

    [InjectionConstructor]
    public ConsumerClass(IServiceInterface service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    IUnityContainer container;
    // blah blah DI setup stuff
    container.RegisterType<IServiceInterface, ServiceClass>();

    // Key point here!
    container.Instantiate<ConsumerClass>();
    // Alternatively:
    container.Instantiate(typeof(ConsumerClass));
}
```

IUnityContainer's BuildUp() method sort of does this, but it requires that you have an instance to pass in, and I can't do this if I want to use injection constructors.

Moreover, I could use:

```
    container.RegisterType(typeof(ConsumerClass), 
        new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IServiceClass>()));
```

However, this is a lot of code to be writing--especially for classes that could have several parameters in the constructor--and seems to remove the utility of the container in the first place.

There's also:

```
    container.RegisterType<ConsumerClass, ConsumerClass>();
```

However with this one, I don't actually want to register the type--I just want it to be created with its dependencies filled via the InjectionConstructor.

So in summary: I want to use injection constructors and I want Unity to do the mapping of registered services for me, and if possible I would like to keep my consumers out of the container. Is there a way to do this that I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, the `.BuildUp` method only works on existing instances, to create new instances using Unity you want to use the `.Resolve` methods, these will create the instance injecting any dependencies as and when required.

For your example use `var consumer = container.Resolve<ConsumerClass>()` and all of the dependencies will be injected. You do not require any registration for `ConsumerClass` because it is a concrete type which Unity is able to handle implicitly.